# SSL Client Certificates Authentication in Mobile Web browsers

Tags: mobile, ssl, browser, client-certificates

I am looking for whether the SSL client certificate based authentication can be done in mobile browsers (mobile safari, mobile firefox, mobile chrome, IE, etc) in iOS, Android, Windows, etc?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it definitely works in Safari on iOS. Not sure about the other browsers and platforms.

On iOS, you can install a digital certificate by clicking a .pfx or .p12 email attachment, which will install the cert in Settings > General > Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome v52.02743.84 (in iOS v9.3.2) does not accept client certificates. As previously aswered it works with Safari in iOS.